# Nested routes without inadvertent top level routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have 3 resources that are structured in a hierarchy as follows:

```
house 1-* residents 1-* books
```

We know that its not great to have deeply nested routes, so we endeavour to have routes nested at most 1 resource deep. Defined something like:

```rb
resources :houses do
  resources :residents
end

resources :residents do
  resources :books
end
```

The problem is that we end up defining `:residents` as a resource that can be accessed without any nesting - as part of the definition of `:books`. Is there way to define `:books` as being nested in `:residents`, without inadvertently registering `:residents` as a top level route?

Comment: This isn't recommended as your users won't be able to 'get back out' in your app by simply deleting off the last part of the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished by using scopes, in your case:

```
scope 'residents/:resident_id' do
  resources :books
end
```

However, as I mentioned in the comment, this practice can end up confusing users who expect URLs to behave in a certain way (deleting the last bit takes them up a level).